# OnBackKeyPress in windows phone only works in staring page

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need handle hardware back button in every pages but it is not working.
I can only invoke OnBackKeyPress in main page. and other pages run same functionality that I put in main page OnBackKeyPress event. 
I googled it more than 2 hours but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what you are doing.  There are two ways to capture the Back key: override OnBackKeyPress of the PhoneApplicationPage class, or attach an event listener to RootFrame.BackKeyPress.  If you are attaching an event listener then even if you leave the current page the event listener will still be attached and will be called whenever the Back key is pressed.  You'll need to be more specific with exactly what you are doing, what you expect to see, and what you are seeing.